# Bootstrap align new row with element in subcontainer of different row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a situation where I need to be able to align a new row with a previous one, but the previous row has been split up in such a way that the alignment/sizing is not very straightforward.  The row that I have to align with is split into two `col-md-6` divs, and one of them is further split into a `col-md-3` and a `col-md-9`.

I need my new row to have one container that aligns with the content in the `col-md-3` container, and the other container should take up the rest of the row.

Here is a summary of the existing row along with the desired format of the new row:

[image]

And here is some minimal code to show what I have:

```
<!--existing row-->
<div class=row>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                Content to align
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                Everything else on this col-md-6.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                Other stuff
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>       
</div>
<!--this is my attempt at the new row-->
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-3">
              New stuff to align
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-md-pull-9">
              Rest of new row.
          </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I cannot align the new row straight away because the existing row is essentially divided into eight columns, and 8 does not divide 12.

The closest thing that I can come up with is to split the new row similar to the existing row into two `col-md-6` containers, the first one split into a `col-md-3`, then have the second `col-md-6` container have a `col-md-12 col-pull-9` div.  That aligns things the way I want them, but the entire row is not filled.  (Can I somehow stretch that element all the way to the end of the row?)

I do not want to change the format of the previous row, and I'd prefer to work within the Bootstrap framework and not have to write any custom containers.  Is there any way of getting the proper alignment and size?

Comment: Please post a minimal example of the code

Comment: Added some code.